# HTML, CSS - Div element positioning within container Div

Tags: html, css

So I have a little circle div that says "request invite" which is inside a larger container div.

I want the circle `#request-invite` div to be positioned in a very particular location (but still flexible and moving with the resizing of the browser window).

At the moment I have got it at the correct location I want, but the position is completely fixed is not flexible with the resizing of the browser window.

Here's what I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/t0j9hwos/

The css that I am struggling with is:

```
#request-invite {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: -10px;
  left: 860px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #d31027;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 22px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Any ideas how I can get the positioning of the `#request-invite` div circle how I want it?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your present solution fits to a particular window width. Let's say that the window is 1200px wide. So you can convert your `left: 860px;` to a relative measurement - relative to the window width. Percentage would be the first choice.

So you calculate, which percentage 860px is in relation to 1200px (your assumed window width - replace that with your actual width value). 860:1200 equals 0,716666... , so that's 71,66666 percent.

So instead of `left: 860px;` you now use `left: 71,6666%;`, or maybe even better `left: 71,6666vw;`. As I said, replace the 1200 with your actual window width (at which the positioning works as desired) when calculating that value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the circle in your example code.

From what I understand, `position:fixed` or `position:sticky` could be what you are looking for.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

You could use `vw` for viewport-width (in percent) and than adjust it using margins like that:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin-top: -10px;
left: 50vw;
margin-left: 20px;
```

[jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/TadWohlrapp/0djuk4zn/) based on your code